# usage of values and annotate in django

Tags: django, annotations, aggregation

I am trying to understand how values() and annotate() works.

In my app, I have a model

```
class MyEntry(models.Model):
    entrydate = models.DateField(default=date.today)
...
```

If I do the following in python shell

```
>>allentries = MyEntry.objects.all()
>>vals = allentries.values('entrydate')
>>vals[:2]
[{ 'entrydate':datetime.date(2013,2,24)},
 { 'entrydate':datetime.date(2013,2,8)}]
```

then,if I apply annotation

```
>>valsannot = vals.annotate(dailycount=Count('entrydate'))
>>valsannot[:2]
[{ 'entrydate':datetime.date(2013,2,24),'dailycount':1},
 { 'entrydate':datetime.date(2013,2,8)},'dailycount':2]
```

When I try this in reverse order

```
>>allentries = MyEntry.objects.all()
>> annot = allentries.annotate(dailycount=Count('entrydate'))
>>annot[:2]
[ <MyEntry ..2013-2-21>,
  <MyEntry ..2013-2-14> ]
>>annot[0].dailycount 
 1 #even tho there are many entries on that date
>>annot[1].dailycount
 1 #even tho there are many entries on that date
```

and then apply values()

```
>>annotvals = annot.values('entrydate')
>>annotvals[:2]
[{'today': datetime.date(2013, 2, 21)}, 
 {'today': datetime.date(2013, 2, 14)}]
```

I am not sure I follow these clearly..Can somebody explain why the reverse doesn't work as the first?

Comment: I'm gonna answer this, but it's gonna take me a bit. The answer is long and I need to check all my facts.